# Calculating how many pixels user has scrolled down page

Tags: javascript

I want to know how many pixels from the top a user has scrolled down my page. So , the number of pixels ABOVE that can't be seen PLUS the number of pixels viewable in the current viewport.

With Jquery I'm using `$(window).scrollTop()` which is showing 612 pixels once scrolled to bottom of page, but `$(document).height()` reports a total height of 1276 pixels.

When I reach the bottom of the page the number I'm wanting to know will be 1276.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Well top is 612.... and the height of the document makes it..... 1276. It is impossible for scrollTop to be equal to the height of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to get is the bottom of the window's current Y offset.

This can be calculated by summing the window's `scrollTop()` and `innerHeight`:

```
$(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#scrollTop").text($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight);
  $("#docHeight").text($(document).height());
}).scroll();
```

```css
body {height: 2500px;}
div {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>scrollTop:</span> <span id="scrollTop"></span>
  <br>
  <span>document Height:</span> <span id="docHeight"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I see your code works in the snippet, but when I put it into its own page the `scrollTop` number is the same as `document Height` and then increases on scroll.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Woops. I used `$(this)` instead of `$(window)` (which works in my example because `this` *is* the `window`). I believe my edit should fix that.

Comment: I picked that up too, but still same result as my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate how much the user has scrolled the page vertically in terms of pixels from the very top, in JavaScript, we would probe either **window.pageYOffset**, or in older versions of IE, one of several variants of **document.body.scrollTop**, whichever property is supported:

```
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop
```

Using jQuery instead, the equivalent would be:

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div style="height:1000px"></div>

<p id="output" style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0; padding:10px; font-weight:bold">
 You have scrolled the page by:
</p>

<script>

var output = document.getElementById('output')

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
 var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
 output.innerHTML = 'You have scrolled the page by: ' + scrollTop +'px'

}, false)

</script>




<script>

/* ### jQuery version below. Uncomment to see: ### */

/*

var $output = $('#output')

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
 var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
 $output.html( 'You have scrolled the page by: ' + scrollTop +'px' )
})

*/

</script>


</body>
```